# Minishift is too slow to load

Tags: openshift-origin, minishift

I have a boot2docker version of minishift installed on my laptop. Since I am using Windows 10 Home edition, I am forced to use Virtual box to run the minishift OS. However, every time I have to load the OS, minishift takes ages to boot up.

It takes almost 15 minutes to fully start the system. Plus I have to rsync my changes again as they are lost every time I stop the machine. Is there any solution to this?